# want to apper menu icon button in top right. in Material Design Lite

Tags: html, css, menu, icons, material-design-lite

I want to move menu-icon-button in top right. But it appears under title. 
what kind of attribute or property should I add?

```
    <!-- Simple header with fixed tabs. -->
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header
            mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Right aligned menu below button -->

<button id="demo-menu-lower-right"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    for="demo-menu-lower-right">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <a href="#fixed-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</a>
      <a href="#fixed-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
      <a href="#fixed-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
      <a href="#fixed-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 4</a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

[here is a image url](http://pix.sevelina.ru/images/2015/08/28/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA1Qgwqc.jpg)

Comment: can you provide your `css` code ?

Comment: you can use `position: absolute` property of `CSS` and position you menu-icon-button, at top-right.

Comment: @Amitsingh there is no css codes related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the menu appears on the right side, you need to add the following `div` inside the `mdl-layout__header-row` element and then add whatever element you want for the right side of the head. Please refer to Material Design Lite on [Layout](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout) for more details.

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>

      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>

      <!-- Right Menu -->
      <button id="demo-menu-lower-right"
              class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>

      <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
          for="demo-menu-lower-right">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
        <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
      </ul><!--/Right Menu -->
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
  </main>
</div>
```

In addition, if you want to change the location of the Menu, you can change the `mdl-menu--bottom-right` to the direction you like. Please refer to MDL [Menu](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section) specs at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header
        mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
       <header class="mdl-layout__header">
          <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
              <div class="row" style="margin:0">
                 <!-- Title -->
                  <span class="mdl-layout-title left">Title</span>

                 <!-- Right aligned menu below button -->

                 <button id="demo-menu-lower-right" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon right">
                   <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                 </button>
               </div>
           </div>
           <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-right">
              <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
                 <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
               <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
              <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
           </ul>
            <!-- Tabs -->
             <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
              <a href="#fixed-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</a>
              <a href="#fixed-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
               <a href="#fixed-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
              <a href="#fixed-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 4</a>
              </div>
            </header>
```

I have edited your given code. Hope that will help

Comment: thank you for response. But your code doesn't work properly see: http://pix.sevelina.ru/images/2015/08/28/12.jpg

Comment: yes, you are right. But you can align left /right element in this way. By putting left and right class to the element. for more help  you can get help from this link http://materializecss.com/helpers.html